# Mad Lib program using Python

Tags: python

Automate the Boring Stuff with Python has a project in chapter 8:
Create a Mad Libs program that reads in text files and lets the user add their own text anywhere the word ADJECTIVE, NOUN, ADVERB, or VERB appears in the text file.

It needs to create the new text file and print the results to the screen.

My solution causes a blank new file to be created and shows nothing in terminal. I am using Python 3.5.1 on OS X.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3


with open("/Users/Maverick/madLibProject1.txt", "wt") as fout:
    with open("/Users/Maverick/madLibProject.txt", "r") as fin:
        for line in fin:
            if line == "ADJECTIVE":
                adj == input('Enter an adjective:\n')
                fout.write(line.replace('ADJECTIVE', adj))
            elif line == "NOUN":
                nou == input('Enter a noun:\n')
                fout.write(line.replace('NOUN', nou))
            elif line == "ADVERB":
                adv = input('Enter an adverb:\n')
                fout.write(line.replace('ADVERB', adv))
            elif line == "VERB":
                ver = input('Enter a verb:\n')
                fout.write(line.replace('VERB', ver))

fname = "/Users/Maverick/madLibProject1.txt"
project = open(fname, 'r')
data = project.read()
print(data)
```

Comment: What's the content of `madLibProject.txt`?

Comment: What's your question? BTW if an input line contains more than the word "NOUN", etc., the `==` test won't do what you want, esp. if the line contains more than one substitution word.

Comment: If you step through the program in a debugger, or at least do an accurate job of simulating by hand how the program runs, step by step, you'll uncover multiple problems.

Comment: I just edited a stupid mistake out of my answer, but I think it's all good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this code:

```
data = "a ADJECTIVE NOUN VERB ADVERB to the NOUN to VERB some NOUN"
for part_of_speech in ["ADJECTIVE", "NOUN", "ADVERB", "VERB"]:
    while data.find(part_of_speech) > -1:
        data = data.replace(part_of_speech, input("enter a %s: " % (part_of_speech.lower())), 1)

print(data)
```

Some things that will help you understand this exmaple:

- documentation for [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)
- documentation for [replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace)
- documentation for [find()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=find#str.find)

Also try adding `print(line)` under your for loop to understand your program better. As others have said, debugging skills are one of the most important things you'll learn as you develop your programming.

Answer (score 0):

As a new python programmer, I put everything so simple.I got a file that named "source.txt" and in it , it is written:
 "The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB.A nearby NOUN was unaffected by these events."
 For todo list, 1.First open the file,take the content.
                2.Take user's input.
                3.Re.sub.(I think the author,wants us to use Re.sub.)
                4.Write new content to a new file.
Here's my code hope to help someone.

```
import re
textfile = open("source.txt")
textcontent = textfile.read()
textfile.close()
print(textcontent)
adjective=input("adjective")
verb=input("verb")
noun=input("noun")
adverb=input("adverb")
textcontent= re.sub(r'ADJECTIVE',adjective,textcontent)
textcontent= re.sub(r'NOUN',noun,textcontent)
textcontent= re.sub(r'ADVERB',adverb,textcontent)
textcontent= re.sub(r'VERB',verb,textcontent)
print(textcontent)
new_fileName = 'new_' + 'source.txt'
new_file = open(new_fileName, 'w')
new_file.write(textcontent)
new_file.close()
print("File is saved as 'new_source.txt'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using python 3.8 on Windows10. User can create there own sentence using the code mentioned in the comments. New to python programming.

```
#python3
#madLibsPrac - to read and change the text files

import os, re

file = input("Create a file name for your work:\n")
madLibsFile = open(file, 'w')
sentence = '''The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was
unaffected by these events.'''

# user can also add his/her own input using above format, use the line below
# sentence  = input("Enter a string containing these word(ADJECTIVE|VERB|NOUN)\n") 
# and can subsequently make the changes using the same code

madLibsFile.write(sentence)
madLibsFile.close()

def start():

    #Make a file on the current directory.
    fileName = input("Enter a file name:\n")
    existsFile = os.path.abspath(fileName)
    print(existsFile) #Gives the absolute path

    if os.path.exists(existsFile) ==  True:

        textFile = open('madLibs.txt')
        textFileContent = textFile.read()
        textFile.close()

        grammerRegex = re.compile(r"ADJECTIVE|NOUN|VERB|NOUN")
        match = grammerRegex.findall(textFileContent) # Creats a list of all matches


        for i in range(len(match)): # Iterate through the list of matches

            userInput = input("Enter a "+ match[i]+ ":\n")
            textFileContent = textFileContent.replace(match[i], userInput, 1) #updating the textFileContent i.e the string

        print(textFileContent)
        newFileName = "new_" + fileName #Creats a new file 
        newFile = open(newFileName, 'w') # Opens it in write mode
        newFile.write(textFileContent)
        newFile.close()

    else:

        print("The File does not exists.")
        start()

start()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem in the manner requested by the question by storing the file contents as a string, using regexes to break the string into a list, scanning through the list to find and replace any occurrences of the placeholder words, and finally converting the list back to a string and overwriting the original text file. See code and comments below.

```
#! python3
# madLibs.py - Prompts user for a text file.
#   At each occurence of ADJECTIVE, NOUN, ADVERB, and VERB, user is prompted for a word.
#   The user's word of choice replaces the placeholder.
#   The file is overwritten with the user's word choices in the same structure.

# Import modules.
import re
from pathlib import Path

# Prompt user for file input.
file = input('Please input a file (path).\n')

# Store the file's contents as a string variable.
filecontent = open(file).read()

# Breaks the string into a list with each word, punctuation mark, or space conserved at an index.
listRegex = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]|[\s]", filecontent)

# Scan through the list and look for placeholder words.
#   At each instance, prompt the user for a replacement and make the substitution.
for character in range(len(listRegex)):
    if listRegex[character] == 'ADJECTIVE':
        adjective = input('Enter an adjective.\n')
        listRegex[character] = adjective
    elif listRegex[character] == 'NOUN':
        noun = input('Enter a noun.\n')
        listRegex[character] = noun
    elif listRegex[character] == 'ADVERB':
        adverb = input('Enter an adverb.\n')
        listRegex[character] = adverb
    elif listRegex[character] == 'VERB':
        verb = input('Enter a verb.\n')
        listRegex[character] = verb

# Convert the new list into a new string.
string = ''
for character in listRegex:
    string += character
print(string)

# Overwrite the original file.
Path(file).write_text(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my way that I just follow skills in the book.
However, I have another version when I read the chapter 7 that has some useful method can help code faster.

```
MadLibs=open('MadLibs.txt','w')
MadLibs.write('The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby 
NOUN was unaffected by these events.\n')
MadLibs.close()
MadLibs=open('MadLibs.txt')
Read=MadLibs.read()
print(Read)


Type=['ADJECTIVE','NOUN','VERB','NOUN']
Typed=[]
for i in Type:
    if i=='ADJECTIVE':
        print('Please enter an ',i)
        Typed.append(input())
    else:
        print('Please enter an ',i)
        Typed.append(input())

newtext=('The %s panda walked to the %s and then %s. A nearby %s was unaffected by these events.' %(Typed[0],Typed[1],Typed[2],Typed[3]))
MadLibs=open('MadLibs.txt','w')
MadLibs.write(newtext)
MadLibs.close
MadLibs=open('MadLibs.txt')
print(MadLibs.read())
```